# Compile the stored procedures as interpreted

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

While reading a PLSQL book I have stumbled upon this piece of code :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE pls_test COMPILE PLSQL_CODE_TYPE=INTERPRETED;
```

Could you please explain how it differs from normal compilation? I was not able to find the answer in the book.

Thank you!

Comment: `INTERPRETED` is the "normal" mode, at least in my experience, and `NATIVE` is rarely used. YMMV.

Comment: Whenever you find something in this book (whatever its is) which the book doesn't explain it's probably worth trying to see what the actual Oracle PL/SQL documentation has to say about it. Each is a link to the section [explaining the difference between `native` and `interpreted` compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS910).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle supports two different compilation modes : INTERPRETED and NATIVE.

**INTERPRETED** is the default mode, that was introduced at the same time as stored PL/SQL (Oracle 7) :

> ... each PL/SQL program unit is compiled into an intermediate form, machine-readable code (MCode). The MCode is stored in the database dictionary and interpreted at run time

In the code you showed, the INTERPRETED part is redundant, as it corresponds to the default compilation mode (unless the command is executed against a server whose default was changed).

**NATIVE** was introduced in Oracle 9, then enhanced and simplified in the following versions :

> SQL modules (packages, triggers, procedures, function, and types) .. are compiled... into native code residing in shared libraries. The procedures are translated into C code, then compiled with a C compiler and dynamically linked into the Oracle process.

This results in faster execution times, as no interpretation is needed at runtime : improvement factor was forecasted from 1.04 to 2.4 in Oracle 10g.

As a conclusion : unless you have a good reason, you want to use NATIVE over INTERPRETED...

For more details and a possible migration path, read [this Oracle 10g FAQ paper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/ncomp-faq-087606.html) and [this post on Oracle blog](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2899).

Comment: "Interpreted code is converted to machine code suitable for your processor"? Aside from the OraFAQ blog you cited, do you have a ref to official Oracle docs which confirm this? My understanding (and the numbers cited in the OraFAQ blog post seem to indicate it) is that interpreted code is compiled to virtual machine code and is then executed by the VM. My recollection is that Oracle chose the Ada VM, initially, at least, as the guys who developed PL/SQL *really* liked Ada, and if you squint at it just right in bad light PL/SQL *does* look a lot like Ada v1.

Comment: @BobJarvis : you may be right... I pulled out a more official documentation end edited the quotes in my answer... Thanks !

Comment: Not a problem. The OraFAQ blog post *could be* correct given that A) Sun Microsystems bought Anamorphic Systems, which had taken technology from the Self project and produced the [HotSpot VM](http://wiki.c2.com/?HotSpotVm) for Smalltalk, which Sun used to develop a just-in-time Java bytecode->native translator, B) Oracle bought Sun, acquiring both Java and the HotSpot JIT VM, and C) applying JIT technology to PL/SQL would be a logical step to take. However, in many years of following Oracle and PL/SQL I've never heard they took that step. Confirmation would be good to have.

Answer (score 0):

Below description summarizes Native vs Interpreted Compilation. Interpreted Compilation is default compilation on Oracle DB. Natively compiled code does not need to be interpreted at runtime thus it executes faster.

> Native compilation is the process by which a stored PL/SQL program is
>   compiled into native code (Pro *C) that does not need to be
>   interpreted at runtime. In comparison, code that is not natively
>   compiled is stored in an intermediate form that must be interpreted at
>   runtime.
>
> PL/SQL native compilation provides the greatest performance gains for
>   computation-intensive procedural operations.

Reference : [[1]](https://logicalread.com/oracle-11g-native-compilation-mc02/#.XCfjzFwzbQU) [[2]](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS910)